Kubernetes FlinkSessionJob launching tow instance of same Job
I use the flink operator session mode to submit a session job, but the UI shows two instances of a same job, how can I solve the problem.

I apply the flink deployment first, when the job life status comes to STABLE. I apply the session job. It works in some situation, but sometimes the question appear.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
